# Democratic gerrymander in California to remove as many Republican seats as possible?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, gerrymandering, california

I am curious about gerrymandering. In California, there are 53 House seats. Of those 53, only 7 are held by Republicans. I know this won't happen for political reasons. But, is there a picture of a hypothetical gerrymander that would likely make California's representation 100% Democratic in the House of Representatives?

Comment: I'm sure it'd be possible to draw one, although I haven't come across one (or looked for it).  Whether it'd actually be valid under CA law is a different question, which Rick Smith does a good job of answering.

Comment: Question appears to asking for a hypothetical, "how can I gerrymander California to be 100% democrat" which I believe would be off topic, although it is perhaps in the same vein as "minimum votes to win Presidential election" questions. The title and word choices make it sound like the questioner has assumed California is gerrymandered (not sure if they actually think that or if its just my reading).

Comment: I believe it could theoretically be done by having exterior districts slice through the interior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

538 published a [web app](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/redistricting-maps/california/) back before 2018 midterms that you may find interesting. You can set different objectives and see how that effects the map (and can look at other states if so interested). Considering the interior of California is relatively conservative, getting 100% Democrat looks difficult to impossible. Their "Democratic Gerrymander" still has 6 districts expected to swing Republican.

However, if you maximize "competitive" districts, it looks like you could eliminate any safely Republican districts. It's important to note that that would, on average, still be better for Republicans in the long run than the current alignment (13.7 expected seats vs. the current 12.0 expected seats).

Answer (score 5):

> [I]s there a picture of a hypothetical gerrymander that would likely make California's representation 100% Democratic in the House of Representatives?

No, gerrymandering in California appears to have been effectively eliminated. Note that "community of interest" in item 4 of the map-drawing process could be used to guarantee one or more seats that could vote Republican.

[California Citizens Redistricting Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Citizens_Redistricting_Commission)

> The California Citizens Redistricting Commission is the redistricting commission for the State of California responsible for determining the boundaries of districts for the State Senate, State Assembly, and Board of Equalization. The Commission was created in 2010 and consists of 14 members: five Democrats, five Republicans, and four from neither major party. The Commission was created following the passage in November 2008 of California Proposition 11, the Voters First Act. The commissioners were selected in November and December 2010 and were required to complete the new maps by August 15, 2011.
>
> Following the 2010 passage of California Proposition 20, the Voters First Act for Congress, the Commission was also assigned the responsibility of redrawing the state's U.S. congressional district boundaries following the congressional apportionment arising from the 2010 United States Census.
>
> The Commission has been criticized by some politicians because "many safe seats in the Legislature could suddenly become competitive."

**Map-drawing process**

> The Voters First Act and Voters First Act for Congress amended Article XXI section 2(d) of the California Constitution to establish a set of rank-ordered criteria that the Commission followed to create new districts:
>
> 1. Population Equality: Districts must comply with the U.S. Constitution's requirement of “one person, one vote”
> 2. Federal Voting Rights Act: Districts must ensure an equal opportunity for minorities to elect a candidate of their choice
> 3. Geographic Contiguity: All areas within a district must be connected to each other, except for the special case of islands
> 4. Geographic Integrity: Districts shall minimize the division of cities, counties, local neighborhoods and communities of interests to the extent possible, without violating previous criteria. A community of interest is a contiguous population which shares common social and economic interests that should be included within a single district for purposes of its effective and fair representation.
> 5. Geographic Compactness: To the extent practicable, and where this does not conflict with previous criteria, districts must not bypass nearby communities for more distant communities
> 6. Nesting: To the extent practicable, and where this does not conflict with previous criteria, each Senate district will be composed of two whole Assembly districts, Board of Equalization districts will be composed of 10 Senate districts.
>
> In addition, incumbents, political candidates or political parties cannot be considered when drawing districts.

Answer (score 0):

A moment about gerrymandering in general (Rick Smith covered the California context well, above)...

Gerrymandering works by numerically concentrating and diluting different voting blocks to change aggregate (averaged) outcomes. The original idea behind districting was that districts would align with 'natural' communities in the populace. A representative was meant to represent the interests of such communities, interests which might flow and change organically as the community faced new problems or encountered new opportunities. Gerrymandering replaces these 'natural' communities — communities of people who live, work, and associate together — with 'artificial' communities constructed to maximize the number of districts which show a majority for one ideological position or party. A typical technique is to cluster as many members of one position as possible into a single district, so that a smaller minority position can create local majorities in the remaining districts. However, gerrymandering is always a trade-off. 'Natural' communities do exist, even if they are difficult to define analytically, and artificial constructs that stray too far from these natural communities are difficult to justify and difficult to maintain in the face of normal population movements. Fine-grained control in gerrymandering efforts is strictly subject to marginal returns.

Gerrymandering is less meaningful for a party that has a clear majority in the populace. In fact, a majoritarian party would prefer an un-gerrymandered system, since that would maximize their potential seats while minimizing risk of condemnation. It is *theoretically* possible for a majoritarian party to gerrymander districts to ensure 100% of districts go their way, but in general it would mean artificially breaking up political enclaves in fairly bizarre and draconian ways. California itself is largely Democratic, but certain areas — Orange County, the Central Valley, some parts of northern counties — are deeply Republican, and trying to break up such enclaves to average out their influence would be both difficult and obvious.